# CSS webkit-scrollbar and safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I tried to make something similar to the new scrollbar of Google using the CSS `::-webkit-scrollbar`. In chrome everything works fine, in safari not.

My CSS is

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{height:16px;overflow:visible;width:16px}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button{height:0;width:0}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{background-clip:padding-box;box-shadow:inset 1px 0 0 #e6e6e6}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover{background-color:#f3f3f3;box-shadow:inset 1px 0 0 #e6e6e6}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active{background-color:#f3f3f3;box-shadow:inset 1px 0 0 #dcdcdc,inset -1px 0 0 #eeeeee}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color:#cccccc;background-clip:padding-box;border:solid transparent;border-width:1px 1px 1px 0px;min-height:28px;padding:100px 0 0;box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 0 #e6e6e6,inset 0 -1px 0 #eeeeee}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{background-color:#999999;box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 1px #c0c0c0}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{background-color:#808080;box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 3px #a6a6a6}
```

I made some screenshot of my problem:

This is chrome and it's ok: https://i.stack.imgur.com/obGOy.png

This is safari when you try to scroll with the mouse (without clicking on it): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br7UX.png

When you use the scrollbar by clicking on it with mouse the scrollbar works, the problem is only when you use the trackpad or the scroll wheel

(I tried with Safari on a Mac, didn't try with Safari on Windows)

Comment: This would be a bug in Safari. Make sure you have the up-to-date version, and if it's still present, [report it as a bug](https://developer.apple.com/BugReporter/) to Apple. ***Note:** There may be a better place to report it -- this was just the first thing I could come up with.*

Comment: I checked if a new version of Safari was released, Safari 6 was released 2 days ago and the problem disappeared.
Sometimes I think I'm just luckless...
Thank you @bfrohs !

Comment: It seems like ios6 prevents you from styling scrollbars!? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510013/css-custom-scrollbars-for-safari-dont-display-on-ios-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with Safari 6.0

It was just a bug

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the below property to auto, for webkit-scrollbar to work in IOS,

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;

!important is required, only if you are overriding some predefined library CSS

else,
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;

would work.