# Hiding scrollbars via css doesn't work in Safari, how to fix it?

Tags: css, safari

I'm trying to hide scrollbars of an html element by means of the CSS rule:

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 0;}
```

It works fine in Chrome, but **doesn't work in Safari**, although is't also webkit-based and should support this rule.

Any ideas, why should it happen and how to fix?

Comment: Try to look on this may be it will helpful for your
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691718/css-webkit-scrollbar-and-safari

Answer (score 12):

Depending on how your element is positioned / layered using z-index, in addition to hiding the appearance of the scrollbar, you may also need to set the width/height of the scrollbar to 0.  Otherwise, the contents that would be contained under the scroll track area may be hidden.

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

For Cross Browser, use following -

```
.hide-scrollbar {
  /*FireFox*/
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /*IE10+*/
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /*Chrome, Safari, Edge*/
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should also add this :

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Also check this answer. Useful [Hiding the scrollbar on an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)

Comment: Thank you for answer! But it didn't help. It's very strange, as it obviously should work for Safari just like it works for Chrome. One more detail, i have this problem in a system based on Sencha ExtJS framework. But i think it's not the cause.