# .element::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none} not working in safari and iOS devices

Tags: ios, css, safari, cross-browser

I was trying to hide scrollbar in for specific ul but wanted to allow horizontal scrolling and I tried below

```
.ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display:none
}
```

it worked for all the browsers and devices except safari and iOS respectively

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding scrollbars via css doesn't work in Safari, how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346527/hiding-scrollbars-via-css-doesnt-work-in-safari-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: this doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work around :

```
  .my-element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
    width: 0 !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent; // HERE IS THE TRICK
  }
```

Comment: It does not work for me! the scrollbars are still appearing on iPhone 6 safari